# What lines are covered by MS Test's unit-tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I want to write a plugin for Visual Studio 2013 (.NET 4.5) in C#, what shows me code coverage info (all tests have written by MS Test - standart utility for testing by MS in VS). Please, give me a prompt about my issue: i want to know which lines of user's code are covered by unit-tests.

Comment: Code coverage already does this for you, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx.

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio 2013 are you using? I think you need Ultimate edition for code coverage out of the box. As for third-party, I think [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) might be worth a look. You can install that via NuGet I believe.

Comment: @JasonEvans, thanks for your answer, but i want to create my own plugin for VS2013 (.NET 4.5)

Comment: @IlyaYefimov I salute your wanting to create your own plugin. That will be a great learning experience for sure.

Comment: @JasonEvans i mean, i don't need Ultimate edition for code coverage. I want to know, how to get lines in code what unit-code cover.